# How to get QED symbol in `amsthm`?

Tags: symbols, amsthm

I am trying to get QED symbol in `amsthm`.

I use `$\hfill \square$`, but I get a slightly different square:

[image]

The one on the right is the QED symbol of `amsmath`.

Comment: `\qedsymbol` and `\qedhere`

Comment: @Sigur can you please write that as an answer?

Comment: See also: [QED symbol in latex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1910493/562769)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QED symbol is stored in `\qedsymbol` command and can be changed using `\renewcommand`.

To insert the QED symbol simply type `\qedsymbol` but if you want to move it to the end of line, use `\qedhere`.

Comment: Depending on the document class/package option used, `\qedsymbol` could be either `\openbox` or `\textsquare`. See [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jq1m.png).